# Residual AC voltage after diode bridge in dual power supply

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, bridge-rectifier, dual

I'm building a +/-24V supply for my first hifi project but I'm having an issue. I use a dual output 28V toroid, doubled P600M diodes for rectifying (to distibute the load and lower heating), with two 7824s and three 7924s in parallel to get stable +/-24V 3A after rectification.

The issue is that I get both AC and DC voltages on the outputs.

I measured:

27,2V AC at the 28V inputs.

12V AC and 24,2V DC at the 7824 input.

6,7V AC and 18V DV at the +24V output.

15,4V AC and -12v DC at the 7924 input.

10,3V AC and -9,3V DC at the -24V output.

What am I doing wrong? The idea is based on the [Hiraga Le Monstre schematic](https://www.hobbielektronika.hu/cikkek/files/385/hiragalemonstreeredetitapegyseg.jpg).

The schematic:

[image: PSU schematic]

Layout:

[image: PSU layout]

Comment: The reservoir caps appear to be entirely absent, vs the 68000 uF in the design you are allegedly following; as well as the decoupling caps around the regulators. And those PCB traces aren't designed to carry any significant current at all. Also, how are you going to fit heatsinks to those regulators?

Comment: The big caps are not added yet, this is just a proof of concept (not meant to have any load) build on a test panel. If I can get a stable +/- 24V, I'll also add the caps to the final build and use copper bars for the high current. The regulators will probably be grouped on heatsinks.

Comment: Well if you omit vital parts of the circuit, why are you surprised it doesn't work?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

*Figure 1. The reference schematic shows resevoir capacitors (1) and (2) which your circuit is missing.*

[image]

*Figure 2. Without the smoothing capacitors you get the purple dotted waveform. With the capacitor you get the black line.*

The voltage regulators give out the specified voltage only when the input voltage is greater than the specified voltage plus a couple of volts headroom. When the input drops below the spec the output follows the input.

---

Parallel connection of diodes is problematic because they have a negative temperature coefficient which means that the one that has the slightly lower forward voltage (typically about 0.7 V) will hog slightly more current, get a little warmer, its forward voltage will decrease, it will hog more current than the other, etc., and may fail if it is not sufficiently rated.

Your voltage regulators may suffer similarly.

---

Voltage regulators require decoupling capacitors. If they are close to the main reservoir cap you can usually omit the input decoupling capacitor. It is unwise to omit the output decoupling capacitor as oscillation may occur.

As usual when designing circuits, pay attention to the recommended circuits in the component datasheet. Ask yourself why the manufacturer recommends a particular layout. Before deviating from the manufacturer's recommendations consider why you think you know better than the folks that designed the components.

---

From the comments:

> The big caps are not added yet, this is just a proof of concept (not meant to have any load) build on a test panel.

OK, but it should be clear now that you hadn't considered why the capacitors were there in the first place.

> If I can get a stable +/- 24V, I'll also add the caps to the final build ...

You need both the input capacitors and the decoupling capacitors on the outputs.

> ... and use copper bars for the high current.

3 A does not require copper bars. 0.5 mm<sup>2</sup> wiring would be more than adequate.

Comment: This can be a problem, I'll try it with a cap. As I mentioned in the other answer, I planned to add the caps later.
Thanks for highlighting the parallel diode problem, I didn't know that. In fact, single diodes may be enough with 6A rating, but I wanted to be on the safe side.

Comment: See the update.